# c token pasting (concatenation) with empty string

Tags: c, macros, concatenation, token

I'm trying to use macro for c code.
However, I stuck in using token concatenation

I have below variables.

```
A, aA, bA, cA ...
```

And, all of these variables used for same function (situation is a bit complicate, so just passing variable is not enough).

If I have only

```
aA, bA, cA
```

Then, I can do using the below macro.

```
#define CALL_FUNCTION(GROUP) \
     FUNCTION(GROUP##A);
```

However, because of

```
A
```

I can't use the mentioned macro anymore.
I tried,

```
#define CALL_FUNCTION(GROUP) \
     FUNCTION(GROUP##A);

FUNCTION(NULL);    
FUNCTION(a);
FUNCTION(b);
FUNCTION(c);
```

But actually, NULL is not empty string, it didn't work.

```
FUNCTION("");
```

Also didn't work.

There are alternative way like,

```
#define CALL_FUNCTION(GROUP) \
    if(GROUP == NULL)\
        FUNCTION(A);\
    else\
        FUNCTION(GROUP##A);
```

However, in this case, I need to write few lines more.
In my case, it cause much more codes.

I googled a lot, but I couldn't solution.
Is there anyone who knows how to token paste with empty string?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass an empty argument and it will effectively concatenate nothing with `A`, producing just `A`:

```
#define CALL_FUNCTION(GROUP) \
     FUNCTION(GROUP##A);

CALL_FUNCTION() // expands to FUNCTION(A);
CALL_FUNCTION(a) // expands to FUNCTION(aA);
```

You can [see this work live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bc65eadedbb5731).

The thing to note is that when you call `CALL_FUNCTION()`, you do not pass zero arguments, as you do with functions. Instead, you pass a single argument - empty. Similarly, `MACRO(,)` calls `MACRO` with two empty arguments. It just so happens that the concatenation behaviour with empty is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a second macro that takes no parameters:

```
#define CALL_FUNCTION() \
     FUNCTION(A);

#define CALL_FUNCTION(GROUP) \
     FUNCTION(GROUP##A);
```

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FUNCTION(x)           printf( # x "\n" )
#define CALL_FUNCTION()       FUNCTION(A)
#define CALL_FUNCTION(GROUP)  FUNCTION(GROUP##A)

int main(void) {
    CALL_FUNCTION();
    CALL_FUNCTION(a);
    CALL_FUNCTION(b);
    CALL_FUNCTION(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A
aA
bA
cA
```

Comment: Your example gives me a [warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35e09df47fec9fbd) about the macro being redefined. It just so happens by luck that the redefinition handles both empty arguments and non-empty ones.